# SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder", API

Tags: java, slf4j

The application works fine in tcServer except for the following error:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

What is the meaning of class path, and where can I find it?

I am a newbie, please explain.

Comment: Please consider giving a proper title for your question. If possible include the relevante code, if you give only an error without a context it can be difficult to help you.

Comment: hi,thank you for your replay.i am trying to install and work on Alignment API in Java.in windows operating system. when i try to run java -jar lib\procalign.jar --help code i am getting following errorSLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J: See slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further detai i couldnt fix it

Answer (score 0):

That error means you're missing a JAR file for an actual implementation of SLF4J. What you should do is download an implementation like [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) or [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) (use the log4j-slf4j-impl JAR, not the log4j-to-slf4j one) and add it to your `lib` directory in tcServer.

Your class path is simply the various library JARs that contain compiled Java code that supplements your application. Check out the related questions to the right for other similar problems with missing SLF4J JAR files.

Comment: hi,thank you for your replay.i am trying to install and work on Alignment API in Java.in windows operating system. when i try to run java -jar lib\procalign.jar --help code i am getting following errorSLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further detai i couldnt fix it

Comment: You'll want to add `-classpath lib\slf4j-simple.jar` or similar to that command to get a logger working.