# Quartz scheduler not running the cron job

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I was trying to use the `CronTrigger` in quartz scheduler. The scheduler is starting but the job is not getting triggered. Following is my code,

```
SchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
DateBuilder.evenMinuteDate(new Date());
JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(Sample.class).withIdentity("job1", "group1").build();

CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 * * ? * *")).build();

scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

scheduler.start();
```

`Sample` class code has only one print statement.

Current output is below,

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Current version ,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Am i missing anything?

Comment: The only thing that the log output says is that you have no usable SLF4J binder on your classpath. It is fairly likely that your scheduler is working correctly and is simply not producing any log output. You might verify this by debugging the application and putting a breakpoint in your `Job`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441068/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-api?rq=1 for a possible solution to your binder issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your example with Sample class implemented:

```
public class TestCronJob {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException {
        SchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
        DateBuilder.evenMinuteDate(new Date());
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(Sample.class).withIdentity("job1", "group1").build();

        CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 * * ? * *")).build();

        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

        scheduler.start();
    }

    public static class Sample implements Job {

        @Override
        public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
            System.out.println("From job: " + new Date());
        }
    }
}
```

and it prints every minute:

```
From job: Tue May 26 17:59:00 EEST 2020
From job: Tue May 26 18:00:00 EEST 2020
...
```

So, it is working as expected. 
In your case it may be something related to logging framework maybe?
I see that you have this message in output:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
```